# reverse a file in Unix shell

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a file parse.txt

parse.txt contains the following

```
remo/hello/1.0,remo/hello2/2.0,remo/hello3/3.0,whitney/hello/1.0,julie/hello/2.0,julie/hello/3.0
```

and I want the output.txt file as (to reverse the order from last to first)using parse.txt

```
julie/hello/3.0,julie/hello/2.0,whitney/hello/1.0,remo/hello3/3.0,remo/hello2/2.0,remo/hello/1.0
```

I have tried the following code:

```
tail -r parse.txt
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this awk command:

```
awk -v RS=, '{a[++i]=$1} END{for (k=i; k>=1; k--) printf a[k] (k>1?RS:ORS)}' parse.txt
julie/hello/3.0,julie/hello/2.0,whitney/hello/1.0,remo/hello3/3.0,remo/hello2/2.0,remo/hello/1.0
```

Answer (score 27):

You can use the surprisingly helpful `tac` from GNU Coreutils.

```
tac -s "," parse.txt > newparse.txt
```

`tac` by default will "cat" the file to standard out, reversing the lines. By specifying the separator using the `-s` flag, you can simply reverse your fields as desired.

(You may need to do a post-processing step to get the commas to work out correctly, which can be another step in your pipeline.)

Comment: Just be careful that the newline will be part of the last field if there is one

Comment: THANK YOU for the proviso that this is part of GNU Coreutils. People so often forget that not everyone uses Linux.

Comment: @EricRenouf - Are there any workarounds for that?  For example, suppose that instead of reversing a single line, OP needed to reverse every line in a file?

Comment: use `rev` to reverse lines

Comment: `rev` is not applicable to this particular problem. `printf "%s\n" abc def ghi | tac` versus `printf "%s\n" abc def ghi | rev`

Answer (score 9):

I like the `tac` solution; it's tight and elegant, but as Micah pointed out, tac is part of GNU Coreutils, which means that it's not available by default in FreeBSD, OSX, Solaris, etc.

This can be done in pure bash, no external tools required.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

unset comma
read foo < parse.txt
bar=(${foo//,/ })
for (( count="${#bar[@]}"; --count >= 0; )); do
  printf "%s%s" "$comma" "${bar[$count]}"
  comma=","
done
```

This obviously only handles one line, per your sample input.  You can wrap it in something if you need to handle multiple lines of input.

The logic here is that we can convert the input into an array by replacing commas with spaces.  Of course, if our input data included spaces, this would have to be adjusted.  Once we have the array, we simply step backwards through it, printing each record.

Note that this does not include a terminating newline.  If you want one, you can add it with:

```
printf '\n'
```

as a final line.

Comment: Simpler, replace `printf '\n'` with `echo`

Comment: You can replace the `read` and `bar=` lines with `IFS=, read -a bar < parse.txt` to directly read into an array, separating on commas

Comment: @glennjackman, you know, I *know* that `echo` behaves consistently as long as you're in bash, but years ago I got out of the habit of using it because of inconsistencies in other shells and operating systems, and I've stuck with `printf` ever since.  Luckily, both `echo` and `printf` are built-ins in bash, so there isn't a serious performance hit. :)

Comment: @DigitalTrauma, good point, and saves a variable.  I did it this way to more clearly explain the steps (arguable I guess; what's clear to me is clear to me), but yes, that optimization is certainly the way to go.

Answer (score 7):

```
perl -F, -lane 'print join ",", reverse @F' parse.txt > output.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

The question is tagged [unix](/questions/tagged/unix) and you have mentioned `tail -r` which suggests you might not be using Linux (with full GNU toolchain), but instead some "real" Unix (BSD variant), e.g. [osx](/questions/tagged/osx).

As such, the `tac` command is not available, but as mentioned in the question, `tail -r` is.  So you can use the following:

```
$ tr ',' '\n' < parse.txt | tail -r | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/,$//'
julie/hello/3.0,julie/hello/2.0,whitney/hello/1.0,remo/hello3/3.0,remo/hello2/2.0,remo/hello/1.0
$
```

Notes:

- This only works for files that have one line, as we are relying on converting commas to newlines and back.  If there is more than one line, then the newlines in between will get converted to commas by the second `tr`.
- The final `sed` is to remove a trailing comma, that was converted from a trailing newline inserted by `tail`

Answer (score 2):

You can use any language to do that

```
xargs ruby -e "puts ARGV[0].split(',').reverse.join(',')" < parse.txt
```

Comment: You'll need to `chomp`, and xargs seems needlessly complicated: `ruby -ne 'puts $_.chomp.split(",").reverse.join(",")' parse.txt`

Answer (score 2):

Emulating `tac` with `sed`:

```
tr , '\n' <parse.txt | sed '1!G; h; $!d' | paste -sd ,
```

Alternatively, if you don't have `paste`:

```
tr , '\n' <parse.txt | sed '1!G; h; $!d' | tr '\n' , | sed 's/,$//'
```

Output:

```
julie/hello/3.0,julie/hello/2.0,whitney/hello/1.0,remo/hello3/3.0,remo/hello2/2.0,remo/hello/1.0
```

Answer (score -1):

Reverse can be done by tac (from cat).  As commented this will reverse the lines not what the OP asked for.

```
tac filename
```

You can still you `tac` if you provide line by line and reverse by not linefeed delimiter but the field separator, here `,`.

```
echo "a,b,c" | tr '\n' ',' | tac -s "," | sed 's/,$/\n/'
```

Comment: The point is to reverse the fields on each line, not reverse the lines in the file.

Comment: @glennjackman Sorry for the incomplete answer.  lines in the files are determined by the separator, which is newline by default.  By changing the separator to the delimiter in the post you can achieve the reversal of the fields.